# qt emit singal in windows threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt

I am developing one QT application. As per my requirement, I need to create one Windows thread where I have to emit one signal to notify to my function which is in different class. When i am trying to emit a signal, I am getting an error: `cannot call member function 'void Device::DataRecieved(QByteArray)' without object emit DataRecieved(Rxdata);`. Are there any possibilities to emit QT signal from the Windows thread. Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
DWORD WINAPI Device::RxThread(LPVOID par)
{
    XLstatus        xlStatus;
    unsigned int    msgsrx = RECEIVE_EVENT_SIZE;
    XLevent         xlEvent;
    char            tmp[100];
    QString         str;
    g_bThreadRun = TRUE;
    TStruct *g_th;
    g_th = (TStruct*)par;
    while(g_bThreadRun) {
        WaitForSingleObject(g_th->hMsgEvent, 1000);
        xlStatus = XL_SUCCESS;
        while(!xlStatus) {
            msgsrx = RECEIVE_EVENT_SIZE;
            xlStatus = xlReceive(g_th->xlPortHandle, &msgsrx, &xlEvent);
            if(xlStatus != XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY)
            {
                switch(xlEvent.tag)
                {
                    // CAN events
                case XL_SYNC_PULSE:
                    break;
                case XL_TRANSCEIVER:
                    break;
                    // LIN events   
                case XL_LIN_NOANS:
                    break;
                case XL_LIN_MSG: {
                    QString         str1;
                    QString         sData;
                    str = "RX: ";
                    if(xlEvent.tagData.linMsgApi.linMsg.flags & XL_LIN_MSGFLAG_TX) str = "TX: ";
                    str1 = "";
                    for(int i = 0; i<xlEvent.tagData.linMsgApi.linMsg.dlc; i++)
                    {
                        str1 = QString("%1").arg(xlEvent.tagData.linMsgApi.linMsg.data[i], 0, 16);
                        sData = sData + str1;
                    }
                    qDebug() << "Receiced Data is" << sData;
                    Rxdata.append(sData);
                    Device::sample();
                    emit DataRecieved(Rxdata);
                    break;
                }
                case XL_LIN_SLEEP:
                    break;
                case XL_LIN_ERRMSG:
                    break;
                case XL_LIN_SYNCERR:
                    break;
                case XL_LIN_WAKEUP:
                    break;
                default:
                    qDebug() << "Nothing found";
                    break;
                }
                ResetEvent(g_th->hMsgEvent);
            }
        }
    }
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Does your class inherit `QObject` and have the `Q_OBJECT` macro included?

Comment: Yes, My class inherits from QObject and have with Q_OBJECT.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you exactly what's wrong: `DataReceived` is a non-static method of the `DataReceived` class, and you're trying to call it without a class instance. Your `emit` line should read e.g. `emit device.DataReceived(RxData);`, where `device` is an instance of `Device`.

Since you're using Qt already, you can put all of this code into a nice `QObject` that will work from any thread. There is no magic to a `QThread`: it **is** a handle to a windows thread, nothing more, nothing less, and has no overhead.

Here's an example of how it might be done. Note that the `Device` would work from the main thread too, but would suffer a bit more latency. I've added placeholders for the code you didn't show.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <windows.h>

enum { RECEIVE_EVENT_SIZE = 128 };
enum XLstatus { XL_SUCCESS, XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY };
enum XLevent_tag { XL_LIN_MSG };
struct XLevent {
   XLevent_tag tag;
};
typedef int XLhandle;
XLstatus xlReceive(XLhandle, unsigned int *, XLevent *) { return XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY; }

class Device : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   XLhandle m_xlPortHandle;
   QWinEventNotifier m_event;
   HANDLE m_eventHandle;
public:
   Device(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent), m_eventHandle(0) {}
   void open() {
      // open the xl port and get the event handle
      m_event.setHandle(m_eventHandle);
      connect(&m_event, &QWinEventNotifier::activated, this, &Device::handler);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void dataReceived(const QByteArray &);
private:
   void handler() {
      unsigned int msgsrx = RECEIVE_EVENT_SIZE;
      XLevent xlEvent;
      XLstatus xlStatus;
      while (XL_SUCCESS == (xlStatus = xlReceive(m_xlPortHandle, &msgsrx, &xlEvent))) {
         switch (xlEvent.tag) {
         case XL_LIN_MSG: {
            // ...
            sample();
            emit dataReceived(QByteArray());
            break;
         }
         default:
            qDebug() << "Nothing found";
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   void sample() {}
};

class Thread : public QThread { using QThread::run; public: ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); } };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   Thread deviceThread;
   Device device;
   deviceThread.start();
   device.open();
   device.moveToThread(&deviceThread);
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: DataReceived(QByteArray) is a signal of the Device class. and actually I have declared a function as static DWORD WINAPI RxThread(PVOID par).can't i emit signal from the static function.

Comment: @user3049522 Use `QObject`, `QWinEventNotifier` and `QThread`. It will make your life easier, as I've shown. Of course you *can* emit signals from anywhere, you just need an instance of the object that emits the signal. The  very first paragraph of the answer tells you exactly **how** to emit a signal from a "static" function. If it's not clear, then ask for clarification.